# Trying to read lines into a dataframe, from a text file before and after a certain string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to read lines from a text file to a dataframe, before and after certain text. E.g. I want to read lines 1 through 5. The position of before and after are not fixed.

```
Export Files
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5

End of Export Files
```

I started writing this, but not sure if I'm in the right direction. Can someone please advise?

```
with open('filename') as input_data:
    
    for line in input_data:
        if line.strip() == 'Export Files':  
            break
    # Reads text until the end of the block:
    for line in input_data: 
        if line.strip() == 'End of Export Files':
            break
```

Comment: how those two starting and ending lines different from other lines?

Comment: Starting and ending lines will literally show the string I have in the example. I want to read the in-between lines.

Comment: you can just use one if condition if data of line not equal staring and ending line then read the data

Answer (score 2):

```
a=[]
with open("try.csv","r") as r:
    a=r.readlines()
a=[x.replace("\n","") for x in a]
a=a[a.index("Export Files")+1:a.index("End of Export Files")-1]
print(a)
```

Because you only need the data between *Export Files* and *End of Export Files*, `a.index` helps in finding the position of the text and `a[x:y]` helps in slicing the array. Also, because you file contains new line, you need to replace `\n` with `""` because it is included in the list elements.

Comment: The OP stated "The position of before and after are not fixed". By doing `[1:6]`, the code assumes the positions are fixed

Comment: @PranavHosangadi you are absolutely right. Edited with explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
read = False
data = []

with open(r'sample.txt') as input_data:
    for line in input_data:
        if line.strip() == 'Export Files': read = True
        if line.strip() == 'End of Export Files': break
        if read: data.append(line)
```

Alternatively if you want them in a dataframe, why not directly load them into it?
pandas can read text files with pd.read_csv() and there you can set start and end as well.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"example.txt", skiprows=0, nrows=5)
```

This is especially efficient if you already know the indexes prior to reading the file. If you do not know it you could find them like this, but this will be rather inefficient since you are opening the file 2x:

```
with open('filename') as input_data:
    for i, line in enumerate(input_data):
        if line.strip() == 'Export Files':
            start = i
        if line.strip() == 'End of Export Files':
            end = i-1
            break

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"example.txt", skiprows=start, nrows=end-start)
```

Comment: how will you know no.of rows?

Comment: If there are more than 5 lines then?

Comment: @karthik, this will read a maximum(if there are less than 5) of first 5 lines only regardless of the number of lines in the file. Also if you dont want headers and want to ignore the headers, use ```df = pd.read_csv(r"try.csv", header=None,skiprows=1, nrows=5)```